# C++ Universal Reference and type deduction of LRef parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, forwarding-reference

Assume we have some code

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T&& param);

int x = 5;
// deduced Foo<int&>(int&).
// Argument type A = int. T = int&.
Foo(x);     

int& rx = x;
// deduced Foo<int&>(int& &&) -> Foo<int&>(int&).
// But... argument type A = int&, an lvalue reference to int.
// Is T = int& or under the hood it is T = int& &?
Foo(rx);
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

> 4) If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction

What I want to know: is 'reference collapsing' rules are applied to deduced type T (not to P, parameter type)?

So do we really have for 'Foo(rx)' T = int& &, which collapsed to T = int&?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for practically all technical purposes, the type of an expression is never considered to be a reference type.  [[expr.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prop#expr.type-1):

> If an expression initially has the type "reference to `T`" ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

The one notable exception is when `decltype()` is applied to an unparenthesized name or class member access expression.  Although the syntax considers the name to be an expression, the semantic result involves the declared type of the name *instead of* the expression's type and value category.

So in your example, `x` is an lvalue of type `int`, and `rx` is an lvalue of type `int`.  After their declarations and initializations, the language makes no distinction at all between them, except again if you use `decltype(x)` or `decltype(rx)`.

This means that template type deduction for `Foo(rx)` works exactly the same as for `Foo(x)`: The type `A` is `int`, not `int&`, and the argument is an lvalue.  By the rule you quoted, `T` is deduced to be `int&`, and when substituting `T=int&` into the function type, the reference-collapsing rule says that `T&&` is `int&`.